# TensorFlow - Defining the shape of a variable dynamically, depending on the shape of another variable

Tags: python, tensorflow

Say I have a certain the Tensor `x` whose dimensions are not defined upon graph initialization.

I can get its shape using:

```
x_shape = tf.shape(input=x)
```

Now if I want to create a variable based on the values defined in `x_shape` using:

```
y = tf.get_variable(variable_name="y", shape=[x_shape[0], 10])
```

I get an error, since the values passed to the argument shape must be `int` and not `Tensor`. How can I create such a dynamically shaped variable without using placeholders?

Answer (score 3):

I'm running out of time so this is quick and dirty, but maybe it helps you to get to your solution... 
It's based on this [(dynamic size for tf.zeros)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34718736/dynamic-size-for-tf-zeros-for-use-with-placeholders-with-none-dimensions)  but extends the idea to tf.Variables. Since your variable needs to be initialized anyway - I choose 0s...

```
import tensorflow as tf
I1_ph = tf.placeholder(name = "I1",shape=(None,None,None),dtype=tf_dtype)

zerofill = tf.fill(tf.shape(I1_ph), 0.0)
myVar = tf.Variable(0.0)
updateMyVar = tf.assign(myVar,zerofill,validate_shape=False)

res, = sess.run([updateMyVar], { I1_ph:np.zeros((1,2,2)) } )
print ("dynamic variable shape",res.shape)

res, = sess.run([updateMyVar], { I1_ph:np.zeros((3,5,2)) } )
print ("dynamic  variable shape",res.shape)
```

Comment: However, in this case  `updateMyVar` is no longer a `Variable`, it's simply a `Tensor`. So you wouldn't be able to do operations like tf.scatter_update or slice assignment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `x.get_shape()`:

```
y = tf.get_variable('y', shape=[x.get_shape()[0], 10])
```

Comment: This still doesn't solve it since the shape of x is undefined, so from x.get_shape() I get TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(None)]), which doesn't allow me to set the shape of y

Comment: Your x is of placeholder [None, None]?

Comment: Yes, it is [None, None]

Comment: get_variable wont work, but you can do something like  : y = tf.random_normal([tf.shape(x)[0], 10])  or y = tf.fill([tf.shape(x)[0], 10], 0.), to get around the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.zeros(shape=[10,20])
x_shape = x.get_shape().as_list()
y = tf.get_variable(shape=x_shape, name = 'y')
```

**Update**

You can't create `tf.Variable` with unknown size. For example this code is not valid:

```
y = tf.get_variable(shape=[None, 10], name = 'y')
```

Answer (score 0):

First argument is variable name.

```
x = tf.zeros(shape=[10,20])
x_shape = x.shape
variable_name ='y'
y = tf.get_variable(variable_name, shape=[x_shape[0], x_shape[1]])
```

Comment: My bad, I forgot to put the variable_name argument on my example. I should have written y = tf.get_variable(name="y", shape=[x_shape[0], x_shape[1]]). The problem remains after this change.

Comment: I guess the example I gave is not a good representation of my actual problem. On my case, the variable x doesn't have a defined shape upon graph initialization, so I am unable to use x.shape to define the shape of y

Comment: then you can just create a copy of the target variable.

Comment: I want to set the shape of y such that only the first dimension is inferred from x. I think now the example illustrates my problem well.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, you cannot create a Variable with a dynamic shape through the `shape` argument, instead you have to pass this dynamic shape through the initializer of the `tf.Variable`.

This should work:

```python
zero_init = tf.fill([x_shape[0], 10], tf.constant(0))
# Initialize
y = tf.get_variable(
    "my_var", shape=None, validate_shape=False, initializer=zero_init
)
```

Note that the shape has to be defined before, or with the first execution of `tf.Session.run(...)`. So if your `x` is a placeholder, you will need to feed a value for it.